# Spring Batch Job with Flows not terminating after completion

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I have the below configuration for a Spring batch job :
First Flow :

```
return new FlowBuilder<SimpleFlow>("flowB")
                .start(stepA)
                 .next(stepB)
                 .next(stepC)
                 .end();
```

Second Flow:

```
return new FlowBuilder<SimpleFlow>("flowNotify")
                .start(stepNotify)
                 .end();
```

ANd my Job configuration is as follows:

```
 Job job =  jobBuilderFactory.get("job1")
                    .listener(customJobListener)
                    .start(stepOne)
                    .next(customDecider).on("STATUS_STOP").to(flowNotify)
                    .from(customDecider).on("STATUS_PROCEED").to(flowB)
                    .end()
                    .build();
            return  job;
```

The job runs fine in both the flows based on FlowExitStatus being returned from the Decider, however after the last step the job doesn't terminate, I need to manually terminate the job.

Can someone please guide me on how to terminate the job after the completion of the last step

Answer (score -1):

I was able to resolve the issue. I had Spring Data JPA repositories in the Spring batch job which was causing the issue as per the below link:
https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-batch-processing/issues/40

Comment: Please mention the steps you took to resolve the issue. The supporting link is appreciated, but your answer is still incomplete.